# Gradient stroke shape

Tags: android-layout, android, android-styles

I want to make a stroke that has a gradient on the stroke and use the stroke as a *background* for a selected button. Is this possible using a `<shape>` or will I need to use a **9-slice image**?

I can connect the parts, I just don't know that a *gradient* on a `<shape>` is possible, but if it is I'd rather do that than create a png image.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Shape (rectangle) supports a gradient fill.  You can also round the corners to get a nice toolbar button effect.

I don't think that stroke supports a gradient, but if you want a gradient stroke around your button you can create two layered rectangles - the first one using your gradient and the second using a solid or a different gradient sized to be 2 pixels smaller in height and width.

Comment: I dare say your answer encompasses the closes thing i'm going to find. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Just as an fyi: I myself most often use the 9patch png for backgrounds on buttons and custom "cells" (just a personal preference - or bad habit probably :-).  But gradients are definitely more efficient and easier to modify.

Comment: I think you're right. 9-slice / 9patch is something I've used before, I just wanted to see if there was another way.